# horizontal divs not vertically aligned

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs side by side with one having more content than the other.

These are what the divs look like together.

[image]

I use `display: inline-block` for the divs to go side by side.  I used float left but I didn't work out to good.

Is there any solutions for this problem?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1om71ey0/)

Comment: display:table; use this

Comment: Thank you so much for quick response!  Idk if you want to post your answer and I could make it the official answer, whatever you want to do but thanks man :)

Comment: But tell me it works????

Comment: Yes of course.  [link](http://i.imgur.com/aJb0fWE.png)

Comment: of course table will works. hahaha

Comment: there I think I marked it as the answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
display:inline-block;
```

Use:

```
display:table;
```

Becuase you are already using floating for both div. Hope this will work for you.